# Со фтором или с фтором?

Tags: стилистика, предлоги

Как правильно писать: со фтором или с фтором?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что предпочтительно всё-таки "с фтором."Предлог «с» более распространен в письменной речи. Специальных правил по употреблению предлога «со» не существует.
В русском языке ряд слов употребляется строго с предлогом «со», таких слов немного, их следует запомнить. Пример: со стула, со мной, со схемой, со словом и др.
Можно отметить, что наиболее часто предлог «со» встречается около слов, первая буква которых – «с».
Предлог "со" пишется перед словами, начинающимися сочетаниями "С, З, Ш, Ж + согласная" или согласной Щ. Ещё может выступать перед словами с буквами "В + С, З, Ш, Ж". 
А также употребляется перед родительным и творительным падежами слов -лев, лёд, лён, лоб, мох, ров, рот ,и перед родительным падеж слов -ложь, рожь. 
Употребляется перед словами -мной, мною. 
Употребляется перед словами –вошь, (вши), весь,(все), всякий, всяческий, вторник, второе, второй, многие, многое.

Comment: Не будет слишком нескромно поинтересоваться первоисточником этих рекомендаций? У Аванесовова (п. 34 - начиная с пятого издания) оговаривается фонетическая мотивация только для сочетаний типа "со с+согласная", "со з+согласная", "во в+согласная", "во ф+согласная". На остальные случаи даже В отношении остальных случаев жестких рекомендация нет...

Comment: Источник - лекции преподавателя университета филфака,пришлось помогать делать контрольную, а я это не помню(кажется, когда училась, у нас этого совсем не было), попросила лекции по культуре речи и морфологии, вот кое-что себе выписала, чего не знала.Так что это наработки профессора университета, а уж насколько этот источник для Вас авторитетен, не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, мне кажется, "с фтором" звучит вполне удобоваримо.

Comment: Но со фтором - это ведь тоже не ошибка? Так можно писать? Или это какое-то устаревшее сочетание?

Answer (score 0):

Орфоэпические словари (Аванесов, например) не дают однозначных рекомендаций, но склоняются скорее к фонетически более простому варианту "со фтором" (ср. "со вторым"). Хотя тут, конечно, много субъективного.

Comment: Спасибо большое всем, кто отзвался!!!