# С вниманием или со вниманием?

Tags: орфография, предлоги

Как правильно говорить и писать: "с вниманием" или "со вниманием"? Сложность в том, что если мы говорим "со всем вниманием", то употребляется предлог "со", а если убрать "всем", то как? "С вниманием" - получается много согласных букв подряд, что плохо сказывается на звучании, но "со вниманием" как-то тоже кривовато звучит.
Как все-таки более литературно: "со" или "с"?

Comment: См также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416857/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13135/%d0%a1%d0%be-%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc

Answer (score 4):

ЭМПИРИЧЕСКОЕ ПРАВИЛО (ответ справочной службы русского языка)

Предлог СО фонетически закономерен перед словами, начинающимися с сочетаний [с, з, ш, ж + согласная] или с согласной [щ]: со ста, со славой, со звездой, со шкафа, со жгутом, со щами. Поэтому: со зверем, но с зайцем.
Также предлог СО употребляется перед формами с начальными сочетаниями [л, ль, р, м] + согласная: со лба, со мной, со льдом, со ртом; также перед сочетаниями [в] + согласная: со вторника, со всеми, со второго.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Использование предлогов С/СО определяется удобством произношения. В определенных фонетических позициях употребляется только СО, но есть переходные варианты, где возможны обе формы. В Нацкорпусе одинаково часто можно встретить "с вниманием" и "со вниманием". В этом случае слово начинается с согласной В, но далее следует сонорный звук.

Answer (score 0):

В ситуациях, когда ухо противится воспринимать, а правила не запрещают, лучше использовать иные обороты, например: внимательно. Язык - это в первую очередь общение, обмен информацией, и, если вы хотите, чтобы собеседник, либо читатель не пропускал ваши слова "мимо ушей", речь должна быть не только грамотной, но и мелодичной.