# "Со взбитыми сливками" или "с взбитыми сливками"?

Tags: предлоги

***Со*** взбитыми сливками или ***с*** взбитыми сливками? Объясните пожалуйста, как правильно и почему.

Comment: Повтор: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416857/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be

Comment: Также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36419/%d0%a1-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc

Comment: Там вопросы были с непохожими примерами, а под приводившиеся правила пример из вопроса не подвести.

Comment: Там сказано (со ссылкой на Грамоту): "также перед сочетаниями [в] + согласная: со вторника, со всеми, со второго". Наш случай.

Comment: К сожалению, это правило - иллюстративного свойства: если начать его применять как обязательное (в+согласная), неизбежны ошибки, напр. в случае "с внешней стороны" (вариант с "со" практически не встречается). Важнее уметь сопоставить варианты фонетически. В одном из ответов там, действительно, есть похожий совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, с "со". Думаю, и вам крайне некомфортно произносить подряд четыре согласных звука, из которых (вдобавок) первый - глухой, а последующие - звонкие. Здесь надо руководствоваться естественными фонетическими законами, формальные же правила правописания здесь играют подчинённую по отношению к устному варианту роль: если произнести данное сочетание можно единственным образом, то циркулярное написание не сможет этому противоречить. Если же по какой-то причине требуется  правило под этот пример, его не так просто найти со ссылкой на авторитетный первоисточник: обычно рассматриваются менее ясные случаи, чем четыре согласных подряд. Вот озадачившиеся в своё время нашли такое (со ссылкой лишь на недоступный ныне пост в "Грамоте"):

> *Предлог **со** фонетически закономерен перед словами, начинающимися с*
>   *сочетаний [с, з, ш, ж] + согласная или с согласной [щ]: со ста, со*
>   *славой, со звездой, со шкафа, со жгутом, со щами, со зверем, но с*
>   *зайцем. Также предлог со употребляется перед формами с начальными*
>   *сочетаниями [л, ль, р, м] + согласная: со лба, со мной, со льдом, со*
>   *ртом; также перед сочетаниями **[в] + согласная**: со вторника, со всеми,*
>   *со второго.*

http://www.trworkshop.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=59013

или (менее строго, с упоминанием уважаемых авторов, но тоже без ссылки на страницы их трудов):

> *Перед **многими** словами, **начинающимися с двух или более согласных**,*
>   *особенно если среди них есть „р“, „л“, „н“, "с" (например – со льдом,*
>   *со шторами, со зла, со всяким, со многими, со мною, со всеми и др.)*

http://www.liveexpert.ru/topic/view/117597-s-ili-so

Comment: Вот действующая ссылка на все подобные ответы Грамоты: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%82

Comment: "Подчинённую **к** устному варианту"? Мне кажется, "к" лишнее. Правильно?

Comment: :) Добавил поздразумевавшееся "по отношению" - просто "подчинённое тому-то" здесь выглядело бы излишне навязчиво (как прямое подчинение).

Comment: Точно! Вроде так действительно лучше всего.)