# Предлог "с" или "со"?

Tags: предлоги

Прошу Вашей помощи. Какой предлог правильно употреблять в предложении:
**Жду тебя в 8:00 у меня под подъездом с/со цветами?**

Хотелось бы увидеть ссылку на правила или получить внятное объяснение.
Всё, что нашёл по данному вопросу, — это форумы.

Comment: Здесь "со" не требуется. "С" здесь сливается с первой частью звука Ц (="ТС"). У Аванесова, например, посмотрите в конце словаря, если Вам так нужна ссылка на авторитетный источник. Там перечислены все случаи когда предлоги (С, В, и К, а также О/ОБ/ОБО) выступают с дополнительной гласной.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Словарь Аванесова нашел только в сканированном виде. Поиском там не воспользуешься, а просмотрев в беглом виде материал после словаря, не нашел употребление предлогов с дополнительной гласной. :(

Comment: В самом конце должно быть. У меня бумажный, только не под рукой он сейчас. Я хорошо помню, что было.  В конце концом посмотрите скан от skava1947 - там почти все то же самое, только в сжатом виде.

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36419/%d0%a1-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13135/%d0%a1%d0%be-%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc

Comment: Хм, @М_Г мне кажется, странно выносить в метки любые предлоги, союзы и др... Ладно ещё частицы "не" и "ни", с ними действительно бывает много затруднений у людей, но если добавлять "с", "в", то потом пойдут "над", "под", "около" и т. д.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Не я создавал метки, но ... Послушайте! Ведь, если метки создают – значит – это кому-нибудь нужно?

Comment: Да, но Вы эту метку выбрали всего лишь в пятый раз. Кто-то может неудачно её создать, а потом в единичных случаях пара человек так же неудачно её повторит. Если бы она была хорошей, она была бы создана как минимум 50–100 раз и как минимум несколькими десятками человек (а не одним и тем же в половине или большей части случаев).

Comment: Если метка "с" существует, значит не надо ее убирать. А если убирать - то везде. Я послал это модератотру. Лично мне кажется удобным использовать ее, чтобы найти все вопросы-ответы по теме "с или со". Метка "предлоги" слишком общая.

Comment: Надеюсь, что вскоре уберут из лексикона предлог "со", похоже что в нём нет надобности. Всё то что содержит "со", можно заменить "с".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Какой предлог стоит употреблять в предложении: "Жду тебя в 8:00 у меня
>   под подъездом с/со цветами"?

Корректно: ***с цветами.***

См. [**Грамота.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/69-ko-dnu):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Грамота.ру также добавляет: "Также предлог со употребляется перед формами с начальными сочетаниями [л, ль, р, м] + согласная: со лба, со мной, со льдом, со ртом; также перед сочетаниями [в] + согласная: со вторника, со всеми, со второго."

Comment: @М_Г: _Грамота.ру также **добавляет**..._ === По-моему, Вы ошибаетесь. Прочтите повнимательнее пункты 2, 3, 4 в приведённых мной рекомендациях. **Не могла**  Грамота.ру **дополнять** их  этими _добавлениями_.

Comment: Вы ссылаетесь на ответ Грамоты на вопрос 289651 (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=289651), я - на 
251490 (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=251490),  271806 (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=271806), 274900 (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=274900)