# Как правильно: С или СО ссоры?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как, на ваш взгляд, будет правильно: ***с*** ссоры или ***со*** ссоры? Теоретически верен второй вариант, но уж больно он режет слух.
Пример: **Не хочется начинать день со/с ссоры.**

Comment: А почему вам это режет слух? "Пылесосить со щёткой" тоже режет? Как раз когда говоришь "с ссоры" предлог вообще не слышится и можно воспринять как "день (чего? какой день?) ссоры".

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Не могу наспех найти выдержку из словаря, но где-то тут уже встречала вопрос про с/со (с/со цветами) и там сказано о том, что "с" сливается с "ц" и поэтому "со" не ставится. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416857/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be Вот я и подумала, что в случае с тремя буквами "с" может быть исключение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что пишет [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%82).

Предлог **со** фонетически закономерен перед словами, начинающимися с сочетаний [**с**, з, ш, ж + **согласная**] или с согласной [щ]: *со ста, со славой, со звездой, со шкафа, со жгутом, со щами.* Поэтому: *со звере*м, но *с зайцем*.

Депутаты нового созыва гордумы начали заседание **со ссоры** с прессой.
*С Пушкиным, кстати, его взаимоотношения складывались сложно: начались [**со ссоры**](https://kulturologia.ru/blogs/241018/41016/) и несостоявшейся дуэли, но закончились крепкой дружбой.*

Ранее РБК **со ссылкой** на данные Росстата сообщил...

*Но как только мы сделали это и пароход с начальством отчалил, двинулся вслед и пароход **со ссыльными*** (В. Н. Фигнер. После Шлиссельбурга).